# What ports should I leave open for MySQL - Ubuntu server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm building a database server that I want to run on a VPS. I'm planning on using IPTables to block unnecessarily opened ports. What are the ports I should be blocking if I only want to access to my server via ssh and mysql port 3306? I want to make sure I'm not blocking some important service.

Comment: You want to block **all** ports first, then unblock only those you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to block all ports excepts the one you need 3306, and 22 if you need your servers to get accessed by MySQL and SSH only, but you need to keep in mind if there are some connections that should be opened in order to update your server and install new packages and that can be only determined by you. here is the list of known ports maybe you are use some of them.

> 20 – FTP Data (For transferring FTP data)
>
> 21 – FTP Control (For starting FTP connection)
>
> 22 – SSH (For secure remote administration which uses SSL to encrypt
>   the transmission)
>
> 23 – Telnet (For insecure remote administration)
>
> 25 – SMTP (Mail Transfer Agent for e-mail server such as SEND mail)
>
> 53 – DNS (Special service which uses both TCP and UDP)
>
> 67 – Bootp
>
> 68 – DHCP
>
> 69 – TFTP (Trivial file transfer protocol uses udp protocol for
>   connection less transmission of data)
>
> 80 – HTTP/WWW(Apache)
>
> 88 – Kerberos
>
> 110 – POP3 (Mail delivery Agent)
>
> 123 – NTP (Network time protocol used for time syncing uses UDP
>   protocol)
>
> 137 – NetBIOS (nmbd)
>
> 139 – SMB-Samba (smbd)
>
> 143 – IMAP
>
> 161 – SNMP (For network monitoring)
>
> 389 – LDAP (For centralized administration)
>
> 443 – HTTPS (HTTP+SSL for secure web access)
>
> 514 – Syslogd (udp port)
>
> 636 – ldaps (both ctp and udp)
>
> 873 – rsync
>
> 989 – FTPS-data
>
> 990 – FTPS
>
> 993 – IMAPS
>
> 1194 – openVPN
>
> 1812 – RADIUS
>
> 995 – POP3s
>
> 2049 – NFS (nfsd, rpc.nfsd, rpc, portmap)
>
> 2401 – CVS server
>
> 3306 – MySql
>
> 3690 – SVN
>
> 6000-6063-X11

Comment: Thanks. I did some digging and read that is several other places as well so I figured why not. Hasn't caused me any problems yet. Thanks!